# equals method and ==operator java

Tags: java, methods, operators

Please look into the below code and help me understand the concept
equals method compares only value of the object while == operator compares references of the objects then why here in the code == operator is returning false even though there are two separate objects created

```
    Ex Obj1=new Ex();//creating Object of Ex class
    Ex Obj2=new Ex();//creating another Object of Ex class
    System.out.println(Obj1==Obj2);//false
    System.out.println(Obj1.equals(Obj2));//false
```

Comment: Can you explain in your own words what a reference is?

Comment: Public class Ex is a class which this entire code is inside Stack overflow did not allow me to write the entire code so posted part of it and Obj1 is of type Ex refering to Ex asn so does obj2 is another new Object refering to Ex

Comment: class Ex  
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  Ex Obj1=new Ex();
  
  Ex Obj2=new Ex();
  System.out.println(Obj1==Obj2);
  System.out.println(Obj1.equals(Obj2));
 }
}

Comment: Please edit the question to apply the code in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

In general both equals() and “==” operator in Java are used to compare objects to check equality but there are some difference between two :

1. Main difference between .equals() method and == operator is that one is method and other is operator.
2. We can use == operators for reference comparison (address comparison) and .equals() method for content comparison. In simple words, == checks if both objects point to the same memory location whereas .equals() evaluates to the comparison of values in the objects.

According to your example,
In 1st comparison you are using "==" for comparing 2 objects. Here both the object have different memory location that's why the output is false.
In 2nd comparison you are using ".equals()" for comparing 2 objects. Here both the objects are different.

Comment: That is my question why is equals method returning false when I have created 2 different object pointing to two different memory location and equals should only campare values at that location the output is false as mentioned but it should be true

Comment: Because you haven't overridden equals() to compare the values. The default Object.equals() does the same thing as ==.

Comment: As explained above, the == operator works on reference and equals() works on content or values. AS you can see both obj1 and obj2 are pointing to reference not to actual values. You can assign any value in empty object via any class variable than you can use equals() method to compare actual content.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is actually like this:
when you define a preliminary class data

```
int val1 = 1;
```

The variable val1 is actually storing 1 in its location.

However, the Object Class data will store the address not the data

e.g. Person person1 = new Person()
person1 is actually storing an address of a Person Class object

The actual comparison of == in different cases
case 1:

```
int val1 = 1;
int val2 = 1;
val1 == val2; // true (as the thing behind is actually 1)
```

case 2:

```
Person person1 = new Person();
Person person2 = new Person();
person1 == person2; //false (as the thing behind is address point to different location)
```

The equals() is actually extends from Object.equals()
You may override or overload the method with the type specific logic for comparing object
e.g.

```
person1.name = tom;
person1.age = 10;
person2.name = peter;
person2.age = 10;
person1.equals(person2);// the result actually depends on the logic defined
```

e.g.

```
public boolean equals(Person obj) { // in this case person1== person2 is true
    return this.age == obj.age;
}

public boolean equals(Person obj) { // in this case person1== person2 is false
    return this.name == obj.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you expected, when compared using == answer is false, as obj1 and obj2 are different object references.

If you look at code for Object.class, the equal method has following code:

```
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (this == obj);
    }
```

[Object class code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java)

The default equals implementation merely does the reference comparison using ==, which returns false. This is the reason why your comparison with equals also returns false.

As mentioned in other answers, no one usually wants this default behavior and that's why you would have to override the behavior and provide your own logic to consider those objects to be equal if they have same content. In this case, same content means no content in both classes.

Comment: What is this keyword doing here also please explain this==obj did not get that

Comment: The method is present in Object class. All your classes extend the object class by default. So when you haven't specified equals implementation, above method is actually executed. In context of above method, as you are executing it on your object `Obj1`, `this` refers to `Obj1`'s reference. 
When you do 
`Obj1.equals(Obj2)`
, here Obj2 reference is passed as parameter. Above method accepts it in a variable named `obj`. Hence the `==` is doing the reference comparison for Obj1 and Obj2.